# NuxtJS passing props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an issue so I have in NuxtJS (vuejs) with a default layout like that

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Loader @animation:complete = 'loader'/>
    <Header/>
    <nuxt :title = 'title'/>
    <Footer/>
    <BgDecor/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { gsap } from "gsap/dist/gsap";

import Loader from "@/layouts/parts/Loader";
import Header from "@/layouts/parts/Header";
import Footer from "@/layouts/parts/Footer";
import BgDecor from "@/layouts/parts/BgDecor";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loaderDone: null,
    };
  },
  components: {
    Loader,
    Header,
    Footer,
    BgDecor,
  },
  head() {
    return {
      titleTemplate: "%s - Product Designer UI/UX Designer Strategist",
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content:
            "Artistic Director, Web / Motion Designer, FrontEnd Developer for over 10 years, specializing in visual communication and web design",
        },
        {
          hid: "keywords",
          name: "keywords",
          content:
            "Product Design, UI, UX, Designer, UI Designer, UX Designer, FrontEnd Developer",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loader(e) {
      console.log("yesssssss");
      this.loaderDone = "yup";
    },
  },
  computed: {
    title() {
      return this.loaderDone;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

my issue is I have yup in Nuxt but not inside the page inside the component nuxt
yes I know it's complicated but I would like to when my loader is done get an $emit to my index page or other pages to know my loader is done
If I put the loader inside the index directly every time I come back to the page index I get again the loader I would like just to have it when I start my website that all
so in the dev tools I have the yup inside the nuxt parent of the index but if I go again with props it seems a lot of work for just getting info my loader is done I can start my other animation

If anyone has an idea thanks :)
have a great evening

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) store.

Your Store could look like this

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loaderDone: false
  },
  mutations: {
    setLoadingDone (state) {
      state.loadingDone = true
    }
  }
})
```

In your loader you could [map the mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components) and in your component you can [map the state](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper).

To set the done flag you can do this in your loader to have the method `setLoadingDone()`

```
// loader.vue
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex}
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['setLoadingDone '])
  }
}
```

And your other componens can get this value like this

```
// other components
import { mapState } from 'vuex}
export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['loadingDone '])
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello thopaw and first of all thanks but it didn't work I put a console log into the mutation into the setLoadingDone function and I got nothing into my loader the setLoadingDone into the loader.vue is a function too right with the same name? and I tried to make 
`endLoader() {
      console.log("fini");
      this.loadingScreen = false;
 },
    setLoadingDone() {
      this.endLoader;
      console.log("hello");
      this.tlHome.play();
    },
    ...mapMutations(["setLoadingDone"]),` and I got nothing not the hello nothing even the console log from the vuex mutation :D

Comment: Hi again I put the setLoadingDone into the onComplete of my loader it seems triggering but I have that  "unknown mutation type: setLoadingDone" even if in my store I have 

`import ProjectService from '@/services/ProjectService.js'

export const state = () => ({
    loaderDone: false
})

export const mutations = {
    setLoadingDone(state) {
        console.log('mutation loader')
        state.loadingDone = true
    }
}

so I have no clue why

Comment: You have to check the docs for mutations (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html). It seems that there is an error in the setup. The vue devtools also are a good help to debug mutations.

Comment: thanks so it's mean my code id incorrect or vuejs has some issues with it? anyway I looked at mutation and put a commit to get the value and still an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined` I have no idea  why because I have the state ( my const is called state not store ) and I called it with the mapMutations from vuex anyway thanks for your help :)